# Как проверить работу cron на хостинге?

Tags: cron, ocstore

Добавил задачу в планировщик на хостинге. Горит галочка что работает, интересует убедиться что он действительно работает. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Прописать запись чего-нибудь в какой-нибудь файл и проверить, что файл действительно записался?

Answer (score 2):

#### 1. Можно посмотреть в syslog что он отрабатывает, например:

```
# cat /var/log/syslog  | grep CRON | tail
Oct 19 15:09:01 G5070 CRON[4412]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && /usr/lib/php/sessionclean)
Oct 19 15:15:01 G5070 CRON[4528]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Oct 19 15:17:01 G5070 CRON[4572]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Oct 19 15:25:01 G5070 CRON[4661]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
```

#### 2. Самому логировать

Например, создать файл  cron_log.txt 
А в ваш скрипт в конце добавить команду, которая например пишет дату время в cron_log.txt. 
Пример:

```
$ crontab -l

*   *   *   *   *   my_cron_script.sh
```

```
$ cat my_cron_script.sh

date >> cron_log.txt
```

Comment: Благодарствую) Уже разробрался.